# Getter Setter returning null

Tags: c#, interface, getter-setter

I have an Interface

```
interface IPerson
{
    PersonInformation PersonInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And this class

```
public class PersonInformation
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

When I implement the interface it's giving me a null error and I can't determine why. My get/set looks correct

```
class Employee: MyStore, IPerson
{
    private PersonInformation _perInfo;

    public override void Execute()
    {
        PersonInfo.Name = "Bill";
    }

    public PersonInformation PersonInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _perInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            _perInfo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything compiles but when I try to set PersonInfo.Name it's saying the object isn't set. I've played around with the get/set in the interface but that didn't change anything. I'm thinking I'm missing something so obvious...any ideas???

Comment: Hint: you need to create an object of type `PersonInformation` at some point. Where do you believe you're doing that in your current code? (I'd also suggest using an automatically-implemented property for `PersonInfo`, given that you're not specifying any custom behavior.)

Comment: Did you forget to set a value for `e.PersonInfo` first? [It works perfectly fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FhfrxL) when you do that. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: You need to create a `PersonInformation`. So in `Execute` create a `new` `PersonInformation` object then assign its name

Comment: The default **initial value** is supposed to be `null`, until you assign (via the setter) an object reference to the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declaring a reference variable member does not create an object for that variable. You must set the variable to refer to an actual object instance.

So you either want this:

```
myEmployee.PersonInfo = new PersonInformation();
myEmployee.PersonInfo.Name = "Some Name";
```

or this in the class definition:

```
private PersonInformation _perInfo = new PersonInformation();

// ...

myEmployee.PersonInfo.Name = "Some Name";
```

---

As a further note, in the latter case you probably would be better off having the `set` be **private**, or not even defining it at all. (Note the interface definition will require otherwise, but I expect you can change that, too).

This is because setting a mere property like `.Name` is still a **get** operation on the parent object: first you get the reference to the entire `PersonInformation` object, and then use the set **on the object's `.Name` property** to set the field.

You only need to use a `set` for this property if you want to replace the *entire object* with a different one (see, for example, the first line in my sample above).